# Tags for water-borne/air-borne/solid-borne acoustics

Tags: discussion, tags

I believe we should think about 3 (?) tags related to the type of acoustic substrate the question is about, it could help to retrieve and understand questions better. I'm not sure of the best keyboards to use, but we could agree on a set of keyboard to use maybe? Tags cannot have 2 words, except there is an hyphen in-between.

This could be air-born/solid-born/water-born, but they may not be the most widespread expressions in the community (?) so other possibilities could be:

- airborne-sounds/vibration/underwater-sounds
- airborne-acoustics/surface-acoustics/underwater-acoustics
- etc

What do you think?

Comment: I think we can eliminate the 'acoustics' part of these tags, since this site will be all about acoustics, and I might suggest simplifying the term (air instead of airborne). If someone is doing vibration in air, they might use both tags.

Comment: Maybe air, water, solid? To keep them short and simple

Comment: Sounds good to me!

Comment: Alternative suggestion for solid: perhaps 'dense' mediums? This is how I often refer to mediums such as compacted earth, wood, etc.

Comment: maybe "substrate" instead of solid. It seems to be the term used in vibratory communication ("subtrate-borne vibratory communication")

Answer (score 4):

Great discussion topic.

I’d vote for underwater-acoustics for the water related topics.

Would it be useful to have a separate marine and freshwater tag, or would we want to encourage all ‘water as the medium’ questions to be tagged ‘underwater’?

I also like ‘in-air’ for ‘gas as the medium’ questions but that is just personal preference for how I typically discuss the differences between underwater and in-air environments and so realize that might not be the same for all.

I am not at all familiar with the solid side of things so am curious to hear what folks think.

Comment: My vote is for 'underwater' or 'water' (not differentiating marine/fresh), since this is a gradient (where would the poor estuarine folks go?).

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion, the conclusion could be (This is a Wiki, please edit):

- air
- water
- substrate